# Pointer assignment not working while debugging

Tags: c, pointers, null-pointer

I have a struct that contains two pointers, < head, iterator > both pointers point to another struct - Node.

```
typedef struct Map_t {

    Node head;
    Node iterator;

} Map_t;

typedef struct Node_t* Node;

struct Node_t {
    MapDataElement Data;
    MapKeyElement Key;

    struct Node_t *next;
};

typedef struct Map_t *Map;
```

I want to make the *iterator* pointer point to the same position as *head*. heres Debbuging before and after runnning the line:

***Before line***
[image]

***After line***
[image]

As you can see, after running the line, the map->iterator still points to 0x0.. Why is that?

Comment: Could it relate to compiler optimization?  Does this happen when you build with no optimization?  Does the update occur after a future step?

Comment: It appears to *not* point to `NULL` (as evidenced by the other values changing), but Eclipse still shows it as `NULL`. Eclipse bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the pointer assignment has occurred as evidenced by your second picture, which highlights the changes to the members of `map->iterator`. I'd imagine the method runs to completion, returning the pointer `0x9918f0`.

This leads me to believe that you're not actually experiencing a failure in pointer assignment, but merely a failure in your debugger (Eclipse) displaying an updated value. This could be due to a bug in Eclipse or it could be due to insufficient debugging information available to Eclipse. It is difficult to say with only the example given.